# Python: Skip url in scraping process conditionally

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, skip, continue

I'm scraping property ads by BS4, using the following code,

```
# get_ad_page_urls collects all ad urls displayed on page
def get_ad_page_urls(link): 
    BS4_main(link) # BS4_main parses the link and returns the "container" object
    return [link.get("href") for link in container.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/inmueble/)((?!:).)*$"))]

# get_ad_data obtains data from each ad
def get_ad_data(ad_page_url):
    ad_data={}
    response=requests.get(root_url+ad_page_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    <collecting data code here>

    return ad_data
```

This works fine. By the following multiprocessing code, I scrape all the ads,

```
def show_ad_data(options):
    pool=Pool(options)
    for link in page_link_list:
        ad_page_urls = get_ad_page_urls(link)
        results=pool.map(get_ad_data, ad_page_urls)
```

**Now the issue:**

Particular ads should be skipped. Those ads display a specific text, by which they are recognisable. I'm new to using `def` functions, I don't know how to tell the code to skip to the next `ad_page_url`.

I think the "skipping" code should be placed between `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')` and `<collecting data code here>`. Something like,

```
# "skipping" semi-code
for text in soup:
    if 'specific text' in text:
        continue
```

but I'm not sure if using `def` functions allows for applying `continue`
on iterations.

How should I modify the code such that it skips an ad when the `specific` text is on the page?

Comment: A def function as you call it is literally just a block of code that runs when you call said function, so yea, if you run a continue inside of a for loop, it will simply go to the next iteration and continue.  The only way to stop the entire function would be to so some kind of sys.exit() or return function call to return out of the 'def function'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a continue or pass will move on to the next iteration skipping if a skip condition is met in the if statement:

```
def get_ad_data(ad_page_url):
    ad_data={}
    response=requests.get(root_url+ad_page_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    for text in soup:
    if 'specific text' in text:
        continue #or pass
    else:
        <collecting data code here>

    return ad_data
```